# Java - Internalisation issue

Tags: java

I have been given the following code in order to internationalise a program, allowing me to use multiple languages depending on what the user chooses.

```
import java.util.*; 
public class I18NSample { 
  static public void main(String[] args) { 
    String language, country; 
    if (args.length != 2) { // default is English-language
      language = new String("en"); country = new String("US"); 
    } else { 
      language = new String(args[0]); country = new String(args[1]);
    } 
    Locale currentLocale = new Locale(language, country); 
    ResourceBundle messages = 
      ResourceBundle.getBundle("MessagesBundle", currentLocale);   
    System.out.println(messages.getString("greetings"));
    System.out.println(messages.getString("inquiry")); 
    System.out.println(messages.getString("farewell")); 
  } 
}
```

This is my MessagesBundle file:

```
greetings = Hello.
farewell = Goodbye.
inquiry = How are you?
```

However when implementing this code in my program, I am not able to use the messages.getString function in other classes, and I need this code in my main as it takes String[] arguments. Is there anyway around this?

Comment: This isn't really an internationalization issue, its a code structure issue. I'll answer the question but it may help get other answers to edit your title.

Comment: Also, there is no need or benefit to copy the strings with `new String (x)`. Just pass `"en" "US"` or `args[0] args[1]` to `Locale`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, Just move the messages intitialization up above your class and make it public, like this:

```
import java.util.*; 
public class I18NSample { 
  public ResourceBundle messages;
  static public void main(String[] args) { 
    String language, country; 
    if (args.length != 2) { // default is English-language
      language = new String("en"); country = new String("US"); 
    } else { 
      language = new String(args[0]); country = new String(args[1]);
    } 
    Locale currentLocale = new Locale(language, country); 
    messages = 
      ResourceBundle.getBundle("MessagesBundle", currentLocale);   
    System.out.println(messages.getString("greetings"));
    System.out.println(messages.getString("inquiry")); 
    System.out.println(messages.getString("farewell")); 
  } 
}
```

That way, you'll b able to access it from other classes using `I18NSample.ResourceBundle`

Answer (score 0):

So what you have here is not an internationalization issue, its a code structure issue.

Your `messages` variable is local to the main method. Make it a field on the class instead then initialize it in main.

The example below is to show you what I mean. It may make sense to initialize your Locale in a similar manner.

```
import java.util.*; 

public class I18NSample { 

  private ResourceBundle messages; //this may have to be static to initialize it in main

  static public void main(String[] args) { 
    String language, country; 
    if (args.length != 2) { // default is English-language
      language = new String("en"); country = new String("US"); 
    } else { 
      language = new String(args[0]); country = new String(args[1]);
    } 
    Locale currentLocale = new Locale(language, country); 
    messages = 
      ResourceBundle.getBundle("MessagesBundle", currentLocale);   
    System.out.println(messages.getString("greetings"));
    System.out.println(messages.getString("inquiry")); 
    System.out.println(messages.getString("farewell")); 
  } 

  //this getter exposes the ResourceBundle so you can use it outside of this class
  public ResourceBundle getMessages() { return messages; }
}
```

Comment: If it's private, how will he be able to access it from other methods?

Comment: `private` fields are accessible to other methods in the same class. If it needs to be accessible to other classes then a public getter method could be readily introduced.

Comment: "I am not able to use the messages.getString function in other classes" I think he needs to access it across classes...which causes a bit of an issue as well because then all of this couldn't be static

Comment: D'oh. This is what I get for helping before coffee. I'll update

Comment: Yes the field must be static to be set (or accessed) from `main` which must be static, and the getter should also be static.